# Each item in a loop is an array. How do I use one item in the array when looping?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a task that loops through some JSON data (it's information about Confluence pages and their attachments, from the Confluence REST API):

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "title": "page0",
      "children": {
        "attachment": {
          "results": [
            {
              "title": "page0attachment0",
              "history": {}
            },
            {
              "title": "page0attachment1",
              "history": {}
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "page1",
      "children": {
        "attachment": {
          "results": [
            {
              "title": "page1attachment0",
              "history": {}
            },
            {
              "title": "page1attachment1",
              "history": {}
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the filter I'm using to loop:

```
var.json.results | subelements('children.attachment.results')
```

This works fine, but when looping for some reason, the page information is the first element then the attachment information is the second element.

For example, in the loop if I call `{{ item.0.title }}` I'll get the following:

```json
"msg": "page0"
"msg": "page0"
"msg": "page1"
"msg": "page1"
```

And if I call `{{ item.1.title }}` I get:

```json
"msg": "page0attachment0"
"msg": "page0attachment1"
"msg": "page1attachment0"
"msg": "page2attachment1"
```

So it appears that the loop contains an array with the page information as the first element, repeated for each attachment and the attachment as the second element.

Again, it's working fine in a regular playbook with a task like this:

```yaml
- name: Get item info
  amazon.aws.s3_object_info:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    bucket_name: "{{ bucket }}"
    object_name: "file/path/{{ item.1.title }}"
  loop: "{{ var.json.results | subelements('children.attachment.results') }}"
```

The problem is I want the task to be separated into a `tasks` directory and use `include_tasks` like this:

```yaml
- name: Get item info
  include_tasks: get_s3_object_info.yml
  loop: "{{ var.json.results | subelements('children.attachment.results') }}"
```

So, since I still need to capture the second element within the loop I don't want to have to write the `item.1.title` thing into the `get_s3_object_info.yml` task because I want to be able to use that task elsewhere so I want to just call `item.title` within that task.

**NOTE** I also need to access the `history` attribute, which is why I can't just get a flat list of attachment titles, I need to iterate through a list of objects that contain both the `title` *and* `history` attributes.

Bottom line--whether by modifying the jinja template, or using `loop_control` or otherwise, how can I turn `item.1` into just `item`?

Maybe something like `var.json.results | subelements('children.attachment.results') | foreach(index=1)` or something like that?

Also, each item has a `type` attribute: `page`, `attachment`, etc. Is there a way I can add a `where(type='attachment')` or something similar?

Comment: Too many questions! and doubts only not having any execution flow and please share the minimum reproduceable code where you have question.

Comment: If you don't care about the informations of the page and only of the attachment, don't stop at that level to do a `subelement`, just continue traversing the JSON object: `var.json.results | map(attribute='children.attachment.results') | flatten | map(attribute='title')`

Comment: This said, you should indeed reduce this to asking one question not multiple as you are doing right now and start with a [mre]. For example, you are speaking about the history of the file but you are failing to explain how it is important in your question and what you need to do / query about it; same goes with the type, which is not part of your example JSON.

Comment: If I had to summarise a question like this it would probably go along the line of _"I need to display the attachments nested in each pages, along with their history. This needs to be done only considering the attachments of `type: attachment`"_.

Comment: `I also need to access the history attribute` <= I changed my answer below to make it possible but it is not at all clear from your example code. For your next questions please take the time to read [ask] paying attention to (already linked by @β.εηοιτ.βε) the [mre] section. Explaining a problem is a skill that has nothing to do with the number of years you have been using a tool. This is why sentences as ["I'm new to X so be kind if I'm not clear enough" should be avoided](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-like-greetings-signatures-thanks-etc-when-editin)

Comment: I agree my question is too verbose, I was struggling on how to accurately describe the problem without giving examples. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

***preliminary note**: having a variable called `var` is anything but a good idea as it is not meaningful and might conflict with other names in ansible/python. I changed the name to `confuence_api_page_request` in the below answer. Adapt to your need*

---

In your included task, just describe the variable exactly as you want to use it, e.g. in `get_s3_object_info.yml`:

```yaml
- name: Get attachment info from S3
  amazon.aws.s3_object_info:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    bucket_name: "{{ bucket }}"
    object_name: "file/path/{{ attachment.title }}"
```

Then pass the variable exactly as needed to your included task file:

```yaml
- name: Get attachment info
  vars:
    attachment: "{{ item.1 }}"
  include_tasks: get_s3_object_info.yml
  loop: "{{ confuence_api_page_request.json.results
    | subelements('children.attachment.results') }}"
```

Moreover, since you are not using the top element page information anywhere in the above tasks, you can easily extract that as a single list from your json and loop directly on the attachement information. Keeping the exact same include file above, just change the `include_tasks` loop to:

```yaml
- name: Get attachment info
  include_tasks: get_s3_object_info.yml
  loop: "{{ confuence_api_page_request.json.results
    | map(attribute='children.attachment.results') | flatten }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: attachment
```

In all cases, you can access history from the included file with `attachment.history`

Note also the second solution will let you use the default `item` loop var in any of your included tasks if needed as the include loop var will not conflict with it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not really using `var` as the variable, for some reason I used that just for this post. But idk why I didn't think about assigning `item.1` to another variable, that makes a lot of sense. Your second example is what I'll probably go with. I'll test it right now and if it works I'll mark this as the answer